# List Append in JavaScript not working with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a list using Firebase and I want to retrieve data and show it in a List form. But the following code is not working. If someone could help.

I not able find a working solution. I tried a table view as well but neither worked. It would be very kind if someone could help out in this case.

```
function newItem() {
  var item = document.getElementById("todoItem").value;
  var ul = document.getElementById("toDoList");
  var li = document.createElement("li");

  var length = document.getElementById("todoItem").value.length;
   if (length == 0 || length < 3) {
     alert("Please Enter a To Do");
     console.log("No Value");
   } else {
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      var uid;

   if (user != null) {
     uid = user.uid;
   }

firebase
  .database()
  .ref("/Users/" + uid + "/todo")
  .push({
    Items: item,
  });

var ref = firebase.database().ref("/Users/" + uid + "/todo");
ref.once("value", (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    console.log(childKey);
    console.log(childData);

    //...
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(childData);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("toDoList").appendChild(node);
   });
 });
}
li.onclick = removeItem;
}
```

Comment: *"is not working"* is quite meaningless by itself without more details about what is different from expected, any errors, what is working and specific part that isn't  and basic debugging details. See [ask]

Comment: Oh ok, so just for more background if you could help. What I want is the data (to do list items) in firebase to be retrieved and displayed in a list view. Which currently is not happening. The only step till which the thing is working is till console.log(childData); as I am able to get everything in the console. Neither is something happening nor is there an error that I could work on.